# How to convert Database/Table Data into a File's Name?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Good Day to all I just wanna ask something about Leaflet Markers.

I have a database and a table with a field that has a name of **icon_name** and it looks like this.

```
|icon_name|
___________
|FIRE     |
|HOMICIDE |
|RAINSTORM|
```

and I also have a folder Named **Legends** and it has a file that looks like this.

```
Folder Name: Legends
Files Inside:

FIRE.jpg
HOMICIDE.jpg
RAINSTORM.jpg
```

as you can see the names of jpg files is the same in my table (icon_name)

My code below is calling a specific image in a folder and uses this as a Leaflet markers image before placing it in the map (Note: The following code is generating the markers info from database into the map)

```
    var Icon1 = L.icon({ //<---Assigning a name of an image into a Leaflet Icon.
        iconUrl: 'legends/FIRE.jpg',//<--- Image Folder Location + the Image Name
        iconSize: [50, 50], //<--- Size of the image converted as icon
        iconAnchor:   [23, 50], //<--- Icons Anchor
        popupAnchor:  [3, -50] //<--- Leaflet Pop up

function getInfo() { 
    $.getJSON("get_info.php", function (data) { 
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
        var location = new L.LatLng(data[i].lat, data[i].lng); 
        var marker = new L.Marker(location,{icon:Icon1}); 
           marker.bindPopup(
              data[i].name + "<br>" + 
              data[i].user_date + "<br>" + 
              data[i].user_time + "<br>" + 
              data[i].address + "<br>"
           ).addTo(map);
           marker.on('click', function(e) { // HERE YOU GO
                var ll = marker.getLatLng();
document.querySelector('#userLat1').value = ll.lat;
document.querySelector('#userLng1').value = ll.lng;
alert('You have selected a Marker that will be deleted'); 

           });
         } 
    }); 
  }
```

Now the output of the code above is like this:

A lot of markers from different parts of the map (good)
All of that markers image is only "FIRE.jpg" even if the other markers has an **"icon_name"** of HOMICIDE,RAINSTORM and others.

Now here is my big question: How can I pass the value of my tables field **icon_name** into the value of var **Icon1 or iconUrl**

```
var Icon1 = L.icon({
iconUrl: 'legends/FIRE.jpg',
```

so that the output will be different markers with different markers image. I hope you understand me. TY

Based on the given answer on me this is my tested code but its not working.

(Part of the code)

```
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
            var location = new L.LatLng(data[i].lat, data[i].lng); 
         var Icon1 = L.icon({
               iconUrl: 'legends/FIRE.jpg',
               marker.bindPopup(
                  data[i].name + "<br>" + 
                  data[i].user_date + "<br>" + 
                  data[i].user_time + "<br>" + 
                  data[i].address + "<br>"
               ).addTo(map);
```

Comment: What does your get_info.php file look like?

Comment: sir my get_info.php is only a php file that consist of a code of select command from my table because i need to call a select command before converting it in leaflet function.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure where you're setting the IconURL, but something along the lines of this should do it.

```
var marker = data[i].marker;
var url = "legends/" + marker + ".jpg";
```

Comment: Sir pls see my edited post. I put some notes on the side of my code so you can review it more. "Icon1 = L.Icon" means that im assigning that my markers name is Icon1 and "IconUrl" is the Image name and its location. So where do i put your answer sir.?

Comment: From what it looks like place it inside of the function that retrieves the info from the php file.

Comment: sir its my first time making this kind of code so im very sorry for that. by the way pls see my edited post, on the bottom of it is the part of my code that has a code of yours and its not working pls help me with this. you can edit your answer with the edited part of your of my bottom code.

Comment: My edited code is located at the bottom of my post which consist of your code too.